# iBeacon.getProximityUuid() can't equal to string?

Tags: java, ibeacon

I try to compare iBeacon.getProximityUuid() with the custom string, but it can't work.
I'm very sure the first char is "a", but the result always return false!
I use the RadiusNetwork's iBeacon library.

```
String tempstr = iBeacon.getProximityUuid().substring(0, 1);
if (tempstr == "a") {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change Change `if (tempstr == "a")` to `if (tempstr.equals("a"))`.  In Java, the `==` operator is used for object equality.  Because the two objects aren't the same instance, `tempstr == "a"` always returns false.  Using the `.equals` method actually compares the strings.